# Sourcetree remove merge commit into develop

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

How can I remove a merge in develop?

I have right clicked on the commit I want to reset to and selected 'reset develop to this commit', using hard mode.

The commit I want to reset too is now bold. Develop branch show updates I need to pull.

How can I remove this merge out of the develop branch completely. If I pull down updates the develop branch resets itself.

The image below shows the commit I have gone back to. Do I have to create another branch from this commit then rename it to develop?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you've [rewritten the history](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) of your local `develop` branch by removing a bunch of commits, you have to [force push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force-with-leaseltrefnamegtltexpectgt) it in order to make the `develop` branch on the remote look like yours.

Here's [how to force push a branch using Sourcetree](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-to-quot-force-quot-push/qaq-p/718539), but, before you do that, beware of the [consequences of force pushing a rewritten shared branch](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#problems-With-rewriting-history).